# Difference between Request.Cookies["Key"].Value and Request.Cookies["Key"].ToString()

Tags: asp.net, httpcookie

Is there any difference in using the following

```
Request.Cookies["Key"].Value
```

and

```
Request.Cookies["Key"].ToString()
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, running the following block of code demonstrates the different outputs:

```
Request.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie("Test", "MyValue"));

Debug.Print(Request.Cookies["Test"].Value);
Debug.Print(Request.Cookies["Test"].ToString());
```

The first debug print will display "MyValue" whereas the second will display "System.Web.HttpCookie".